# Regular Expression to match dates in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regular expression in PHP that looks for the date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD

What I have is: `[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}`

I'm using preg_match to test the date, the problem is that `2009-11-10` works, but `2009-11-1033434` works as well.  It's been awhile since I've done regex, how do I ensure that it stops at the correct spot?  I've tried doing `/([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}){1}/`, but it returns the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need is anchors, specifically `^` and `$`. The former matches the beginning of the string, the latter matches the end.

The other point I would make is the `[]` are unnecessary. `\d` retains its meaning outside of character ranges.

So your regex should look like this: `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/`.

Answer (score 7):

```
^20[0-2][0-9]-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])$
```

I added a little extra check to help with the issue of `MM` and `DD` getting mixed up by the user. This doesn't catch all date mixups, but does keeps the `YYYY` part between `2000` and `2029`, the `MM` between `01` and `12` and the `DD` between `01` and `31`

Comment: This was useful but there's one small mistake - it excludes the days 10 and 20.  It should use: `^20[0-2][0-9]-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$`

Answer (score 3):

How do you expect your date to be terminated ?

If an end-of-line, then a following `$` should do the trick.

If by a non-digit character, then a following negative [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) `(?!\d)` will similarly work.

Comment: Using [^\d] will capture the non-digit character. Using a negative lookahead assertion would be better, as in `(?!\d)`

Answer (score 2):

you're probably wanting to put anchors on the expression.
i.e.

```
^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}$
```

note the caret and dollar sign.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want look ahead assertions (assuming your engine supports them, php/preg/pcre does)

Look ahead assertions (or positive assertions) allow you to say "and it should be followed by X, but X shouldn't be a part of the match).  Try the following syntax

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=[^0-9])
```

The assertion is this part

```
(?=[^0-9])
```

It's saying "after my regex, the next character can't be a number"

If that doesn't get you what you want/need, post an example of your input and your PHP code that's not working.  Those two items can he hugely useful in debugging these kinds of problems.

Comment: A positive lookahead assertion will fail if it encounters the end of the string. Using a negative lookahead assertion like `(?!\d)` is better.

Answer (score 1):

`[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}?`

where the question mark means "non-greedy"

Comment: `\d{2}?` and `\d{2}` are identical. `{2}` already explicitly says match 2 of these atoms, so the greediness of this group has no effect.

Comment: @Kevin B: thx. But why would $ as EOL work in the original `2009-11-1033434` example and not the `{2}`?

Comment: Because the $ matches the end of the string. `\d{2}` matches two digits, but doesn't say that the string has to stop there. `\d{2}$` says "match two digits, then ensure that we've reached the end of the string".

Well, to be more specific ^ and $ actually match line beginning/end in a multiline context, but in a non-multiline context they match string beginning/end. There's also `\A` and `\z` (or `\Z`), which always match string beginning/end regardless of multiline context.

Comment: OK, I haven't gone completely insane, only a little ;-) I know about the EOL concept and understand it in the way you described. But I thought: He obviously has a string like `abcdef2009-11-1033434abcdef`.With the regexp he matches `2009-11-1033434`. So why would the EOL (or end-of-string in this context) trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting both a '^' and a '$' symbol at the start and end of your expression:

```
/^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}$/
```

which match the start and the end of the string respectively.