# Matching "magical" dates with regex

Tags: regex, date, datetime, date-formatting

I've found a regular expression which matches "magical" dates (in which the last two digits of the year are the same as the two digits of the month and day, for example 2008-08-08):

```
\b[0-9][0-9]\([0-9][0-9])-\1-\1\b
```

... but I can't understand it. How does it work?

Comment: So does it work for, you and you don't understand it, or does it not work for you?

Comment: You've failed to explain a problem or ask a question. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711727/62576 will help.

Comment: I want to understand it, it does work for me thanks. i will be glad if you try to explain it in more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the same regex, written verbosely with comments:

```
\b            # The beginning or end of a word.
[0-9]         # Any one of the characters '0'-'9'.
[0-9]         # Any one of the characters '0'-'9'.
(             # Save everything from here to the matching ')' in a variable '\1'.
    [0-9]     # Any one of the characters '0'-'9'.
    [0-9]     # Any one of the characters '0'-'9'.
)             # 
-             # The literal character '-'
\1            # Whatever was saved earlier, between the parentheses.
-             # The literal character '-'
\1            # Whatever was saved earlier, between the parentheses.
\b            # The beginning or end of a word.
```

In the case of '2008-08-08', the '20' gets matched by the first two `[0-9]`s, and then the '08' immediately after that gets matched by the next two `[0-9]`s (which are in parentheses, so that '08' gets saved to the variable `\1`).

Then a hypen is matched, then `08` again (because it was stored in the variable `\1` earlier), then another hyphen, then `08` (as `\1`) again.

Comment: That was awesome explanation thanks i got it now thanks Wish i can up vote this answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
\b[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})-\1-\1\b
```

Last 2 digits are captured in captured group #1 and then back-reference of captured group i.e. `\1` is used in month and date part later.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lV0nW5/1)

Comment: can you explain it please

Comment: Added an explanation and demo in answer.